# Timestamp conversion from one timezone

Tags: java, datetime

I need to convert the timestamp from one timezone to another time zone and  retrieve the time in milliseconds for that timezone.
I tried doing that below, but its not working out.

```
 SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          localDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("anothertimezone));
          //Current Date Time in Local Timezone
          System.out.println("Current Date and Time in local timezone: " + localDateFormat.format( new Date()));
          Calendar calendar = localDateFormat.getCalendar();    
          System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

The `calendar.gettime` is printing the current machine's time and not the time based on the timezone.

Comment: If you adjust the time zone, you will still have the same number of milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: hello basil, i didnt quite get you..

Comment: I think timestamps are the same? Datetime in different zones are different

Comment: @oxygenan The stock markets in New York open at 9:30 AM. In Walla Walla, Washington (state), someone watching the market needs to be on their computer at 6:30 AM (three hours behind New York time). Adjusting from New York time zone to Walla Walla time zone means adjusting 3 hours. The person in New York and the person in Walla Walla are both watching the market open at the same moment in time. Both 9:30 in New York and 6:30 in Walla Walla are the same moment in the history of the Universe, and are both represented by the same number of milliseconds since the epoch (beginning of 1970).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but this prints the current time in CEST and IST:

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = 
      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println("Current Date/Time in local timezone: " + 
                       localDateFormat.format( new Date()));
localDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
System.out.println("Current Date/Time in IST timezone: " + 
                       localDateFormat.format( new Date()));
```

You can also take a date and time in string form and parse it:

```
 // create a string showing date and time in IST time zone 
 String istDateString = localDateFormat.format( new Date());
 Date istDate = localDateFormat.parse( istDateString, new ParsePosition(0) );
 System.out.println( istDateString + " parsed to " + istDate );
```

The default used in Date.toString is, of course, the local setting.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting time zones leaves you with the same milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 is much easier than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. While a java.util.Date has no time zone, a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object in Joda-Time does indeed know its own assigned time zone.

Here is some example code. All of these DateTime objects represent the same moment in the timeline of the Universe, that is, the same number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (the beginning of 1970). To verify, call the [`getMillis`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29) method to extract the number of milliseconds.

```
String inputRaw = "2014-01-02 03:04:05";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" ); // Convert to strict version of ISO 8601 standard format.
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeParis = new DateTime( input, timeZoneParis ); // Interpret that string as being in a particular time zone.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTimeParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis millis: " + dateTimeParis.getMillis() );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc millis: " + dateTimeUtc.getMillis() );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal: " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal millis: " + dateTimeMontréal.getMillis() );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-01-02T03:04:05
dateTimeParis: 2014-01-02T03:04:05.000+01:00
dateTimeParis millis: 1388628245000
dateTimeUtc: 2014-01-02T02:04:05.000Z
dateTimeUtc millis: 1388628245000
dateTimeMontréal: 2014-01-01T21:04:05.000-05:00
dateTimeMontréal millis: 1388628245000
```